# DataDirect Azure ODBC Connection Refused

Tags: sql-server, azure, odbc, datastage, datadirect

I'm trying to establish a connection to my Azure database using DataDirect ODBC driver but I'm getting this error.

```
Src_ODBC_Unld_iMIS_Name_All: ODBC function "SQLConnect" reported:  SQLSTATE = 08001: Native Error Code = 0: Msg = [IBM(DataDirect OEM)][ODBC SQL Server Wire Protocol driver]Connection refused. Verify Host Name and Port Number. (CC_OdbcConnection::connect, file CC_OdbcConnection.cpp, line 578)
```

My connection info.

```
[ODBC Data Sources]
AzureSQLServer=DataDirect SQL Server Azure
[AzureSQLServer]
Driver=/opt/IBM/InformationServer/Server/branded_odbc/lib/VMsqls00.so
Description=DataDirect SQL Server Native Wire Protocol
Database=AzureDatabase
EncryptionMethod=1
HostName=azure-db-server.database.windows.net
PortNumber=1433
ValidateServerCertificate=1
```

I'm able to connect to the database by setting up an ODBC from Windows with the SQL Server Native Client driver and I get a successful audit log entry for the database. When using the DataDirect driver, I'm not even getting an audit log entry on the Azure database. Does that indicate that the DataDirect connection isn't even getting past my firewall or is there an issue with my settings?

Answer (score 2):

The driver is not getting past your firewall from this machine. The error means the driver could not resolve the hostname to an ip address and/or found that the port requested was not listening. It's not likely an issue with the port, so try to ping azure-db-server.database.windows.net. It will likely fail to ping, but the output will show whether the machine where the driver is installed is able to resolve the name to an ip address. If the name is not resolving to an ip from this machine, then you should check your network or firewall settings to see what needs to change in order to get the name resolution working.

Also, with ValidateServerCertificate=1, you'll need to provide a valid Truststore in your data source definition. You may want to set this to 0 while you work to get the initial connection established.